# pause c# program for few second?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pause C# program for few second , I don't want to use system.threading.thread.sleep , is there any other way to pause program .

I want to show window for some second and automatically minimize.
I added two timer one for maximize window and one for minimize;
when window maximize I want to stay there for few second if I use sleep method it don't show text on form . so is there any way to pause the window for few second.

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "pause". If sleep isn't what you mean, I don't know what you do mean.

Comment: why don't you want to call `Sleep`?

Comment: If you don't want to use sleep, use a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you don't want to use `Sleep` the only thing left is to use timers like this:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer1= new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(maximizeScreen);
timer1.Start();

private void maximizeScreen(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    //Do the maximizing

    //disable the timer
    ((System.Timers.Timer)source).Stop();

    System.Timers.Timer timer2= new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    timer2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(minimizeScreen);
    timer2.Start();
}

private void minimizeScreen(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    //Do the minimizing

    //disable the timer
    ((System.Timers.Timer)source).Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can use the [`Delay` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845.aspx) on the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235678.aspx) to wait for a predetermined amount of time, like so:

```
private async void MaximizeScreenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    //Do the maximizing

    // Hold off for two seconds.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), cancellationToken);

    // Minimize the screen.
}
```

Note the use of the `cancellationToken` parameter, you would pass a [`CancellationToken` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) (created from a [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx)) to cancel this if need be.

The `MaximizeScreen` method assumes that you're manually triggering the showing of the screen initially.

The [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)/[`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) keywords here will make sure that the code after the call to `await Task.Delay` runs on the proper [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (which is important if you are performing UI operations such as minimizing and maximizing a window.  Also note that this is *not* the case if you call [`ConfigureAwait` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) with a parameter of false on the `Task` that's returned from the call to `Task.Delay`).

Note that the call to `MaximizeScreen`, because it is marked as `async`, will return immediately once the call to `async Task.Delay` is reached, so you shouldn't expect that the screen is minimized when complete.

If you want to wait until the screen is complete, then I'd recommend that you expose a task and wait on it.

First, modify the signature to return a `Task` (nothing else changes):

```
private async Task MaximizeScreenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

And then at the call site, just call the [`Wait` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321315.aspx) on the `Task` returned (using the same `CancellationToken` that you'd pass to `MaximizeScreenAsync`):

```
MaximizeScreenAsync(cancellationToken).Wait(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: You'd need to build cancellation into this (not that it would be that hard to do); it appears to be a business case that the timer can be cancelled.

Comment: @Servy Updated to include cancellation.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You may have kind of a splash screen to wait. This is a simple windows form, which shows some text message and stays open for some interval:

```
public partial class WaitWindow : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public WaitWindow(int interval)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Shown += new EventHandler(WaitWindow_Shown);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = interval;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    void WaitWindow_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

It uses timer to close in a given period of time. At least you may use it like this:

```
new WaitWindow(1000).ShowDialog();
```

When talking about windows forms, it's more appropriate to use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as:

> This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and
>   must be used in a window.

while [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

> The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a
>   multithreaded environment.